# Error while installing spark manually

Tags: laravel, installation, laravel-5, laravel-spark

I have downloaded the spark v1.0.5 and extracted in my laravel-project root with name "spark" then i have updated my composer.json file with repository and the require and laravel-project's composer.json looks like this

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "daem0ndev/laravel-spark": "dev-master",
        "intervention/image": "^2.3",
        "felixkiss/uniquewith-validator": "2.*",
        "laravel/cashier": "~6.0",
        "laravel/spark": "~1.0"

    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
    },
    "repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "./spark"
    }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

After this when i run command from my laravel-project directory
`composer update`
it shows the following error

`php artisan clear-compiled
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.`

Problem 1
    - The requested package laravel/spark could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more details.

Read https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for further common problems.

Comment: The [official install instruction](https://spark.laravel.com/docs/1.0/installation) says `"laravel/spark": "*@dev"` if this changes anything.

Comment: Yup!., it solved my issue thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add this "laravel/spark": "*@dev" , for details check [here](https://spark.laravel.com/docs/1.0/installation)